# Cassandra throwing org.apache.cassandra.config.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate dse.yaml

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to run sstable2json utility after starting cassandra server but it throwing following error.
Fatal Configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.config.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate dse.yaml

Fatal Configuration error; Unable to start server.

command: bin/sstabel2json /opt/dse2.1/dse-data/UserDemo/Users-hd-3-Data.db > Users.json

Before this: i started server by passing system parameter
command:bin/cassandra -f -Ddse.config=file:/opt/dse2.1/resources/dse/conf/dse.yaml

Eventhough it is througing this error.

Please let me know why cassandra throwing this error while invoking sstable2json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you add /opt/dse2.1/resources/dse/conf/ to the classpath

Comment: Thanks, It started working after adding to classpath.It helped me lot.